# Creating CSV file with special characters in fields

Tags: excel, csv, utf-8

I have looked for similar questions on stackoverflow but I haven't found any.
I want to export a table in CSV format so that it can be imported into Excel.
Each cell contains text and each row has the same number of columns.
The format I have tried is the following:

```
"d1"|"d2"|"d3"|"d4"
```

where d1, d2, d3, d4 are the original strings I want to put in each cell.
I have the following problems:

1. | can be contained in the data. Is this really a problem? Maybe not because I have double-quotes around the strings. Maybe I could even use commas and it would not make a difference.
2. " itself can be contained in the data. Should I escape it in some way? My current solution is to remove leading and trailing double-quotes from the original string before putting **my** double-quotes around it. It seems to work, but I think escaping the internal double-quotes would be cleaner. Do you know how to do this?
3. The data can contain newline characters too. I would like Excel to keep the data together in one cell, and to format the text within that cell according to the newlines. At the moment, this is not the case: Excel interprets newlines as terminating a record and adds extra lines in the imported table.

Do you have any idea how to fix the above issues? Is there some online documentation regarding these specific problems? I been searching since yesterday but did not find anything.

Comment: Your language of choice probably already comes with a CSV escaper/writer. What do you want to implement this in?

Comment: Which language are you writing in ? find a library in that language (Also all the escaping etc is a reason to use XML as the interchange format)

Comment: I am writing it in Java. It is not much work, but I just need to know how to handle double-quotes, newlines, and commas (or other field separators) inside fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel supports newlines in values. For example, using the Excel user interface, you can get `"foo\n\bar\nbaz"` into a cell by typing Alt-Enter for each line-break.

The tricky thing about Excel is that in locales where the comma is used as a decimal point, Excel uses a colon as the field delimiter. There is no universal/international format that any Excel will read.

I'd be very surprised if there wasn't a package in Java for reading/writing CSV files. [Python has one](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/csv.html) that allows you to specify the delimiter, quote char, record separator, etc on both input and output.

However if you want to write your own, follow this pseudocode for each row that you want to write:

```
for each field in the row:
    if field contains quotechar:
        double all quotechars in field
        field = quotechar + field + quotechar
    else if field contains delimiter, CR, or LF:
        field = quotechar + field + quotechar
    else:
        avoid waste of space and ugly visual impact by NOT doing unneeded quoting
join field strings separated by delimiter
append CR LF 
write the row string using binary mode (so Windows runtime doesn't give you 2xCR)
```

Note carefully (1) all of the above is premised on 8-bit characters (2) I have avoided using the ambigous term "newline".

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I have implemented it in Java. I have doubled all quote chars in fields and put double-quotes around them. Since the file is not that big I have double quotes everywhere. I have CR LF at the end of records. Still, new lines inside a field are not handled correctly: they are interpreted as end-of-record markers and the data is not imported correctly. I output UTF-8 and specify UTF-8 during import.

Comment: Regarding the newlines in my data: it comes from an XML file which contains a mixture of data from different sources. There are newlines in some fields, which I expected are either CR LF or LF. I want them to be imported into Excel as if they had been typed in using Alt-Enter as you describe. Should I translated these newlines (CR + LF or LF) to LF?

Comment: You shouldn't need to mess with your input CRs and LFs -- quoting all fields as you are doing should protect them. I suggest that you create a small file using Excel (which version are you using? how exactly are you importing the CSV file?) and save it as CSV. Check that you can open it again with Excel. Then verify your expectations by using a char/hex dumper to see exactly what you have in the files that you have created by Java and by Excel. Hint: use formulas when creating test cases in Excel. E.g. `="foo"&char(13)&char(10)&"bar"` produces `foo\r\nbar` in your output file.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer: I had to move to other things and could not work on the CSV problem. I followed your tip: created a small Excel file with two cells. The first cell contains two lines. The output looks as follows: "first line\nsecond line\n";second field\r\n So, double quotes are put around the first field and a NL is used as line delimiter. Then, the sequence CR NL is used as record delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

I find CSV is best done with comma separation, and quoting values so commas in values aren't misinterpreted. Quoting quotes is done with double quoting.  So the following four values:

```
one
two
three with "quoted" value
four
```

becomes:

```
one,two,"three with ""quoted"" value",four
```

I don't believe it's possible for standard CSV implementations to support newlines in values; particularly not in Excel.  Try creating a cell in Excel with newlines (is that even possible?) and saving as CSV to see if that works.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values

Comment: Use `Alt-Enter` to insert a newline while you are entering data to an Excel cell